# RecyclerView прокручивание и подгрузка внутри ScrollView

Tags: recyclerview, nested-scrollview

Есть изображение, снизу текст, а уже после них приходит RecyclerView, текста бывает много и естественно я вставил NestedScrollView после чего при подгрузке элементов интерфейс стал лагать. Если не отключить NestedScrollEnabled, интерфес тогда не лагает но элементы прокручиваються отдельно. Как сделать чтобы прокрутка было нормальной, но без лагов. Код ниже.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.vuqo.shopogram.SellerProductsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/sltoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
        app:title="Satıcı"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/slscroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/add_sell_detail"
        android:layout_below="@id/sltoolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backImage2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/backimg" />

                <com.vuqo.shopogram.CircleImage
                    android:id="@+id/shop_image"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/user" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameofshop"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/shop_image"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/todo"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shop_descCard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/nameofshop"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/todo"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/filtersLinear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/shop_descCard"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/pricefilterspin"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="3">

                </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/viewchange"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/list" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/filterbutton"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/filter" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/shop_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/sellerprprogress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/empty_seller_products"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/m_hsul_tap_lmad"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Код активити.

```
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.shop_recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(grid);
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(adapter.isEnd()){
                if(page<pages)
                    page++;
                query.setPage(page);
                UpdateList();
                adapter.setEnd(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправил с помощю CoordinatorLayout. В коде активити нечего не изменил. Вот XML код. Обычный CollapsingToolbarLayout. Сверху мои элементы, а в самом конце Toolbar.
В Include layout распологается RecyclerView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.vuqo.shopogram.SellerProductsActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backImage2"
                android:src="@drawable/backimg"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

            <com.vuqo.shopogram.CircleImage
                android:id="@+id/shop_image"
                android:layout_below="@id/backImage2"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
                android:src="@drawable/user" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shop_descCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/shop_image"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/todo"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/sltoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```